# Config existing project (GCC) with Xcode 5 - LLVM compiler

Tags: xcode, llvm, xcode5, llvm-gcc, llvm-clang

I have an existing project  that has some third party libs are compiled by LLVM-GCC 4.2 compiler

Now, I need to compile with Xcode 5 that only supports LLVM 5.0

I just wonder if I can compile third party libs as static library (using LLVM-GCC 4.2) and use them in the new project that is compiled by XCode 5 (LLVM 5.0)

Thanks.

Comment: In fact, I did implement this solution and seeing it's working. Just wonder it's good to do so?

Comment: Does the code use callbacks or any string passing? I can't give a thorough answer, but my experience has generally been that I've had issues leading to EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors when trying to combine the clang-compiled code with gcc-compiled dylibs, and usually the errors seem to intermittently occur. 

My guess from experience is that you might have some memory allocation mismatch issues for certain types of function calls, but it may work for simpler libraries that aren't passing pointers.